# How to apply spatial correction to field data based on many randomly dispersed check varieties with varying levels of replication?

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model, spatial

I have inherited a dataset with a truly chaotic trial design. 32/155 varieties are duplicated at least once, most having 2-4 reps, but one is repeated x5, another x8, and another x19. I was told that the 'blocks' are just the four columns. Here's a link to the trial design:

https://nbicloud-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mjones_nbi_ac_uk/ESIUBnup2dBHkqsHob7EvrgBh2saqh1Q4ls8lqSed_v1zA?e=Oyt8nW

I've colour coded varieties that are repeated 4+ times and italicised those repeated 2-3 times to give a better sense of the design.

I have a load of phenotypic data for each plot and I'd like to apply some kind of correction for field spatial heterogeneity. I've looked into using SpATS and I think it's close to what I need, but I don't think any of the five specifiable field designs quite fit my data. (Incomplete block design, resolvable incomplete block design, randomized complete block design, row column design, resolvable row column design.)

Can anyone help me wrangle some kind of BLUEs/BLUPs/breeding values out of this mess? (Or point me to a better forum to ask this question!)

Many thanks,
Max